# How to get path or root of plugin folder, not file or dir?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, directory, paths

I want to include one file from the plugin root to somewhere in the plugin folder.
Folder structure:

```
/plugin
  /folder <- Can't 'esacpe' from this folder to root
    /otherfolder
      /req-file-to-here.php // fetch here
  /req-file-from-here.php // send from here
```

What to exactly type in file `req-file-to-here.php` ?
I have tryed something like this:

`require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '..path to file';`

or

`require plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) . '..path to file';`

Not working. Help :)

Comment: The `content_url()` will take you to your `wp-content` folder and then you can traverse to plugins folder . `plugins_url()` Retrieves a URL within the plugins or mu-plugins directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just define a constant that stores the plugin's root path?

> **Define path constant**
>
> For calling numerous files, it is sometimes convenient to define a
> constant:
>
> ```
> define( 'MY_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
> include( MY_PLUGIN_PATH . 'includes/admin-page.php');
> include( MY_PLUGIN_PATH . 'includes/classes.php');
> // etc.
> ```

— See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/#comment-491

So in your main plugin file:

```php
define( 'MY_PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
```

And then in `folder/otherfolder/req-file-to-here.php`, do:

```php
require MY_PLUGIN_PATH . 'req-file-from-here.php';
```

Alternatively, you could define just the path to the main plugin file:

```php
define( 'MY_PLUGIN_FILE', __FILE__ );
```

And then in `folder/otherfolder/req-file-to-here.php`, do:

```php
require plugin_dir_path( MY_PLUGIN_FILE ) . 'req-file-from-here.php';
```

Comment: PS: Sorry, I copied-pasted the wrong URL.. the correct one is [`https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/#comment-1113`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/#comment-1113).